# Unable to add elements to BIN, In callback function of "pad-added"

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I would like to create a dynamic pipeline, which need to be modified based on the reading file ".ts"

In the reading, file i might have only one video stream, or it might be two videos, or it might also have text data.

If the file has two videos, then if i add two videosinks and one appsink for text data, then i am not able to play the video.

Then, i try to add that element in callback function, then whenever text data comes, it is not working.

Here i attached the code.

```
void uuCMediaPlayer::DemuxLinking(GstElement *Demux, GstPad *DeMuxPad, gpointer data)
{
    uuCMediaPlayer* pObjPlayer = (uuCMediaPlayer *)data;
    int linkFlag = 0;

    char* pad_name = gst_pad_get_name(DeMuxPad);
    UU_PRINT("Player :: In dynamic ADDING PAD %s", pad_name);

    if(g_str_has_prefix(pad_name, "metadata"))
    {
        if(!gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pObjPlayer->mpPlayerPipe), pObjPlayer->mpMetaSink))
        printf"Failed to Add Meta Sink !!");
        printf(" Player :: In dynamic ADDING Meta PAD %s", pad_name);
        GstPad *metasink = gst_element_get_static_pad(pObjPlayer->mpMetaQueue, "sink");
        if(GST_IS_PAD(DeMuxPad) && GST_IS_PAD(metasink))
        {
            if(gst_pad_link(DeMuxPad, metasink) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK)
            {
                UU_PRINT( "Player ::Failed to Link Demux with Meta Queue !!");
                pObjPlayer->mRunFlag = 0;
            }
            else
            {


                    gst_element_link_many(pObjPlayer->mpMetaQueue, pObjPlayer->mpMetaCapsFilter,
                        pObjPlayer->mpMetaKlvParse, pObjPlayer->mpMetaParseCapsFilter,
                        pObjPlayer->mpMetaSubParse, pObjPlayer->mpMetaSink, NULL);
                    //gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pObjPlayer->mpPlayerPipe), pObjPlayer->mpMetaSink, NULL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UU_PRINT( "Player ::Failed to Link Demux with Meta Queue !!");
            pObjPlayer->mRunFlag = 0;
        }
    }
else if(g_str_has_prefix(pad_name, "video"))
{
    UU_PRINT("Player :: In dynamic ADDING VIDEO PAD %s", pad_name);
    if((!pObjPlayer->mDlLinkFlag) && (!linkFlag))
    {
        GstPad *dlsink = gst_element_get_static_pad(pObjPlayer->mpDlQueue, "sink");
        if(GST_IS_PAD(DeMuxPad) && GST_IS_PAD(dlsink))
        {
            if(gst_pad_link(DeMuxPad, dlsink) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK)
            {
                UU_PRINT( "Player :: Failed to Link Demux with DL Video Queue !!");
                pObjPlayer->mRunFlag = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                /** adding elements to bin */
                 gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pObjPlayer->mpPlayerPipe), pObjPlayer->mpDLVideoDecoder,
                    pObjPlayer->mpDLVideoParse, pObjPlayer->mpDLVideoSink,
                    NULL);
                gst_element_link_many(pObjPlayer->mpMetaQueue, pObjPlayer->mpDLVideoDecoder,
                    pObjPlayer->mpDLVideoParse, pObjPlayer->mpDLVideoSink,
                    NULL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UU_PRINT( "Player :: Failed to Link Demux with DL Video Queue !!");
            pObjPlayer->mRunFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    else if((!pObjPlayer->mIrLinkFlag) && (!linkFlag))
    {
        GstPad *dlsink = gst_element_get_static_pad(pObjPlayer->mpIrQueue, "sink");
        if(GST_IS_PAD(DeMuxPad) && GST_IS_PAD(dlsink))
        {
            if(gst_pad_link(DeMuxPad, dlsink) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK)
            {
                UU_PRINT( "Player :: Failed to Link Demux with DL Video Queue !!");
                pObjPlayer->mRunFlag = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pObjPlayer->mIrLinkFlag = 1;
                linkFlag = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UU_PRINT( "Player :: Failed to Link Demux with DL Video Queue !!");
            pObjPlayer->mRunFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    else
        UU_PRINT("Player :: Ignoring the Video Stream !!");
}
```

In place of

```
pObjPlayer->mDlLinkFlag = 1;
                linkFlag = 1;
```

I am adding the videodecoder and xvimagesink elements to the pipeline bin. And,

I tried to link the tsdemux with video decoder and then xvimagesink.

But the video is not playing. If i add those outside of the callback function then it is working fine.

Comment: I think this is wrong approach, you should listen to pad-added signal of demuxer and upon every new pad check its caps and then add/link whatever you need on that pad - this is standard approach and there are tutorials on that - use your favourite search engine, HTH

Comment: oh this is in pad added.. sorry I read the question wrong.. the name of the function is quite confusing

Comment: thats ok, is my approach is correct or not? is there any mistake in this approach?

Comment: why are you not checking caps for `video/something` and for example `subpicture/...` ? why it is called metadata? .. you should check if its video.. and if yes then link video branch containing for example h264 decoder. If its the text then link the pipe that you showed in snippet. I do not see handling of video part in your code..

Comment: you say you are adding the elements but code is not there? or I do not understand the comments after code.. if you do not show the code .. and no logs then how are we going to guess what you did wrong? please make it [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise its impossible to answer.. anyway try to synchronise the elements with pipe after linking with gst_element_sync_state_with_parent

Comment: I updated the adding part.

Comment: While adding like this some of the sink elements are went into pause state even the pipeline is in PLAYING state. When i set the sink state to PLAYING its working fine. But why it is happening?

Comment: I think its a bug.. I had to do the same thing once.. I added elements and set pipeline to playing but sink didnt go to playing so I set it manually.. but the sync state with parent should work.. or have you already did that?

Comment: i didn't used gst_element_sync_state_with_parent. I manually set the sink element state to PLAYING.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the gst1-java-core java bindings.  I had to call play() on the bins I added to my pipeline inside the pad callback.  I'm not sure what the exact method call would be in your non-java code.

Maybe other elements of the discussion at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gstreamer-java/Zvf-3ZAhAwg/fekxcsJDCAAJ will help you make progress.